# Error returning the ArrayList - incompatible type of return for the method (Beginner)

Tags: java, interface

this is my code over here. The issue I am facing is, I want to return a sequence of integers for which I plan to use an ArrayList of integers. The following is my class that's implementing the interface named IntSequence.

```
import java.util.*;
public class IntArray implements IntSequence {

int[] a;

public IntArray(int size) {
    a = new int[size];
}

@Override
public int length() {
    return a.length;


}

@Override
public int get(int index) {

    int use = this.a[index];
    return use;
}

@Override
public void set(int index, int value) {
    this.a[index] = value;
}



@Override
public IntSequence subSequence(int index, int size) {
    ArrayList<Integer> valuelist = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = a1; i <= a2 + a1; i++)
    {
        if((a1 + a2) <= a.length)
            valuelist.add(a[i]);
    }
    IntArray cObject = new IntArray(size);



    return new IntSequence() {

        @Override
        public int length() {
            return a.length;

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public int get(int index) {
            return null;

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void set(int index, int value) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public IntSequence  subSequence(int index, int size) {
            return  (IntSequence) valuelist;
        }
    };
}
}
```

Here's my IntSequence interface -

```
public interface IntSequence {

    int length();

    int get(int index);

    void set(int index, int value);

    IntSequence subSequence(int index, int size);
}
```

**PROBLEM** -  What I am returning in the subSequence is an ArrayList which is an incompitable type to return for that method. I am a begineer and honestly have no idea how this can be solved. (I'm not allowed to change the parameters of the methods and yet manage to do this).

Thanks in advance for taking your time to look at this I really appreciate it!

Comment: what is the actual problem you are facing? why do you tell that the return type is incompatible.

Comment: Because it expects an IntSequence type return type however, I am returning an ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return the ArrayList, not the new IntArray.

Don't use an ArrayList. Create the

```
    IntArray cObject = new IntArray(size);
```

and then set the values onto that. i'll leave that bit to you :)

then just... (no need for that inline class)

```
    return cObject;
```